# HTML 5 CSS 3 Web Browser Control for C#

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control

Is there a web browser-type control that supports much of html 5 and css 3 for C#?

Just asking as I viewed my site designed for modern browsers, but viewed it in the .NET Winforms browser, and it looked rubbish, as that control doesn't support html 5 or css 3.

Thanks, I look forward to hearing from you all.

Comment: actually what you use is just a wrapper control that is shared with internet explorer. so what you see is actually IE's rendering. try upgrading internet explorer to latest version since the latest version is playing nice with newer standards. btw of course anyone who uses your software also needs the latest version of IE. but there are some webkit/gecko wrappers around too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is [Awesomium](http://awesomium.com/) which is based on WebKit (Same as Chrome and Safari). It's not entirely free though (unless you're an indie developer making 100k or less or using it for non commercial development).

The `WebBrowser` control support of HTML5 and CSS3 features depends on the version of IE that is installed. (which means that you can install IE9 on the machine to get better support of these features)